# Default constructor is misunderstood for function name

Tags: c++, constructor

When I compile the following code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Room
{
    int length;
    int width;
public:
    void display()
    {
        cout << length << ' ' << width;
    }
    Room()
    {
        length = 0;
        width = 0;
    }
    Room(int value = 8) : length(value), width(value)
    {}
};
int main()
{
    Room objRoom1;
    objRoom1.display();
}
```

I get the error

> call of overloaded ‘Room()’ is ambiguous

I tried changing `Room ObjRoom1;` to `Room ObjRoom1();` to fix it but when I did that I got

> request for member ‘display’ in ‘objRoom1’, which is of non-class type ‘Room()’

This is because the compiler thinks `Room ObjRoom1()` is  function declaration with name `ObjRoom1()` and the return type `Room`. Can you help me with the exact fix for this code.

Comment: Your class is private by default,you know that?

Comment: Which one should it call if you don't provide a parameter? The one without parameters or the other one with a default parameter? The other issue with the function is known as "most vexing parse" in C++.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, formally no. *Most vexing parse* is for another syntax.

Comment: @Vucko And that comment is relevant how?

Comment: *Can you help me with the exact fix for this code.* -- The fix is not to design your constructors where there is an ambiguity.  Only *you* know the real solution, since it's *your* class design.  All we can say is *why* you get the error.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ dunno, just sayin' cause I was late to answer, at least some contribution from me lol

Comment: @Borgleader No, both constructors are declared `public`.

Comment: The most vexing parse is a name for the common failure to understand that anything that can be parsed as a function declaration is *by definition* a function declaration. How does that not apply to the OP's attempt to fix the ambiguity, @SergeyA?

Comment: I don't understand what the title has to do with the question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, because it's usage is reserved for something like `A a(A());`, not simple `A a();` It is clear from the first sight that the later is a function declaration. It's much harder to see a function declaration in the former. By the way, Wikipedia concurs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Some people do categorise `A a()` as MVP for "simplicity", but it's not strictly one.

Comment: At the end, just remove one of the constructors and you are ready to go.

Comment: Wikipedia only gives examples using parameters, the initial statement concerning the ambiguity is what is important. Anyway, the authority is not Wikipedia but Scott Meyers and if you read the original, you will find that the faulty call to a parameterless constructor also falls under that name, it is explicitly mentioned as an example there. Check out e.g. http://www.uml.org.cn/c%2B%2B/pdf/EffectiveSTL.pdf, page 21 near the bottom.

Comment: BTW: The probably best way to disambiguate between function declaration and initialization is `A a{};` in C++11. I just wanted to point that out, because it wasn't mentioned here yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Room(int value=8)` sets a default value for `value`.  This means you can call it without specifying a value, so you could call it like

```
Room foo;
```

`Room()` takes no parameters.  This means you can call it like

```
Room foo;
```

How is the compiler supposed to know if you want to use `Room(int value=8)` or `Room()` when you use `Room foo;`?  It can't, so you get the error.

Answer (score 8):

You have two versions of constructor - one taking no arguments, another one taking one defaulted argument. Both are default constructors by definition, and compiler can't decide which one are you trying to call.